# How to add the new columns based on counts identified by conditions applied to multiple columns in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose following is my dataframe

**df**

| userId | deviceID | Clean_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 202030 | 28-Jul-22 |
| XYZ123 | 304050 | 27-Jul-22 |
| ABC123 | 405032 | 28-Jul-22 |
| PQR123 | 385625 | 22-Jun-22 |
| WER123 | 465728 | 2-May-22 |
| XYZ123 | 935452 | 22-Mar-22 |

I want to have output like which `user_id` with multiple devices on same day as `'P1'`, `user_id` with multiple devices on different days as `'P2'` and else `'NA'`

Following as sample output

**df_output**

| userId | deviceID | Clean_date | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 202030 | 28-Jul-22 | P1 |
| XYZ123 | 304050 | 27-Jul-22 | P2 |
| ABC123 | 405032 | 28-Jul-22 | P1 |
| PQR123 | 385625 | 22-Jun-22 | NA |
| WER123 | 465728 | 2-May-22 | NA |
| XYZ123 | 935452 | 22-Mar-22 | P2 |

Suggest the solution in pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count distinct `deviceID` per `userId` and per `userId` + `Clean_date` using Window then using `when` expression calculate `Priority` based on counts like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("ABC123", 202030, "28-Jul-22"),("XYZ123", 304050, "27-Jul-22"),
    ("ABC123", 405032, "28-Jul-22"),("PQR123", 385625, "22-Jun-22"),
    ("WER123", 465728, "02-May-22"),("XYZ123", 935452, "22-Mar-22")
], ["userId", "deviceID", "Clean_date"])

w = Window.partitionBy("userId")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("userId", "Clean_date")

df = df.withColumn(
    "Priority",
    F.when(F.size(F.collect_set("deviceID").over(w2)) > 1, "P1")
    .when(F.size(F.collect_set("deviceID").over(w)) > 1, "P2")
    .otherwise("NA")
)
df.show()

# +------+--------+----------+--------+
# |userId|deviceID|Clean_date|Priority|
# +------+--------+----------+--------+
# |ABC123|  202030| 28-Jul-22|      P1|
# |ABC123|  405032| 28-Jul-22|      P1|
# |PQR123|  385625| 22-Jun-22|      NA|
# |WER123|  465728| 02-May-22|      NA|
# |XYZ123|  935452| 22-Mar-22|      P2|
# |XYZ123|  304050| 27-Jul-22|      P2|
# +------+--------+----------+--------+
```